# ActivityLogger::performedOn() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, int given,

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Why `update` does not return a Model instance , some can assist me.

Controller

```
public function cancel_bill_cash_store(Request $request){

            $sales_cancel=Sales::where('bill_number',$request->bill_number)
                    ->update(["cancel_bill" =>1,
                       "bill_status"=>$request->bill_status,

                      ]);

    if ($sales_cancel) {

                          activity('Sales')
                          ->performedOn($sales_cancel)
                          ->causedBy($user)
                          ->log('Cancelled Bill by ' . $user->name . ' with IP '.request()->ip());

                          toastr()->success(' Bill- '.$request->bill_number.' Imeshakuwa Cancelled Vizuri!, 
                          Device Zimerudi Store');
                                 return redirect()->back();
                            }
                          else{
                          toastr()->error('Error: Kuna Kitu Kimekwenda Wrong !. Otherwise check Support.');
                             return redirect()->back();
                           }
       }
```

Comment: Retrieve the model, modify it and then do `->save`. It will be two queries but if you both want to update the model as well as retrieve it there's no alternative. In addition `->save` may be faster than `update` because in some DBMS the update it performs has a limit of 1 so the db may not need to scan through an entire index or table for all matches

Comment: Kindly can you show an example of save base on my code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a "divide and conquer" approach. Split your function into two and have one handle only the update and logging and the other handle the query:

```
public function cancel_bill(Sales $sales_cancel, $bill_status) {
    $sales_cancel->cancel_bill = 1;
    $sales_cancel->bill_status = $bill_status;
    $result = $sales_cancel->save();
    if ($result) {   
        activity('Sales')
           ->performedOn($sales_cancel)
            ->causedBy($user)
            ->log('Cancelled Bill by ' . $user->name . ' with IP '.request()->ip());
    }
    return $result;
}

public function cancel_bill_cash_store(Request $request) {
    $sales_cancel=Sales::where('bill_number',$request->bill_number)
        ->first();
    if ($sales_cancel && $this->cancel_bill($sales_cancel, $request->bill_status)) {
       toastr()->success(' Bill- '.$request->bill_number.' Imeshakuwa Cancelled Vizuri!, 
                          Device Zimerudi Store');
                                 return redirect()->back();
       } else {
         toastr()->error('Error: Kuna Kitu Kimekwenda Wrong !. Otherwise check Support.');
         return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

This gives each function a clear responsibility, one is responsible for updating the model and the other to create responses given the outcome.

Edit: If you have many rows you need to update you can do:

```
function cancel_bill_cash_store(Request $request) {
    Sales::where('bill_number', $request->bill_number)
        ->get()
        ->each(function ($sales_cancel) use ($request) {
            if ($sales_cancel && $this->cancel_bill($sales_cancel, $request->bill_status)) {
                toastr()->success(
                    ' Bill- ' . $request->bill_number . ' Imeshakuwa Cancelled Vizuri!, 
                          Device Zimerudi Store');
            } else {
                toastr()->error('Error: Kuna Kitu Kimekwenda Wrong !. Otherwise check Support.');
            }
        });


    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This will update each row and log the appropriate event.

Comment: Am checking.. and get you feedback

Comment: i tried the code it works but `  toastr()->error()` does not works and it update one row, while
one `bill_number` has many row

Comment: it works well but note that i can not get success massage, `toastr()->error()` or `toastr()->success()` why ?

Comment: in case i can show you if you dont mind, anyDeskID `468 739 406`, then you will update the answer as well

Comment: melx6060@gmail.com